# How to merge several google map images into one?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, google-maps, merge, aerial-photography

I want to have a high resolution aerial photo of a catchment area. I took some images from google maps and georeferenzed these and saved them as a layer file. but how can I merge them now that I have one image for the whole catchment area?

The merge tool didn't work. The images are .png s.
I'm sorry, I'm new to ArcGIS and I couldn't find an answer in the web. Also a mosaic layer doesn't seem what I want...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What are the reasons for you to merge them? Unless they provide any data (like elevation) you are not likely to notice the difference between one merged raster dataset and several overlapping layers. If you still want to combine your rasters I believe that the [Mosaic function](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000098000000) is what you need.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your fast reply! I have like 100 images for the whole catchment and thought I'd needed to merge them before clipping them to the size of the catchment area? Can I also use the clipping tool on the mosaic layer?

Comment: That should not be a problem. Don't add an extension for the output raster, which would make it an ESRI GRID. And those can be clipped as you like. If you like, try it out first on only a few rasters, because I suspect it might take some time to process that many, just to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

The [Mosaic to new raster function](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000098000000) is what you need. Don't add an extension for the output raster, which would make it an ESRI GRID, which can be clipped as you like.